# How does "Remote tab title format" in Konsole work?

Tags: ssh, terminal, konsole, window-title

Some terminal programs, in particular Konsole supports "Remote title format" which allows you to specify title for remote tabs which includes placeholders like remote host. How does this work? Where does it get the remote host from, and how does it recognize the tab is holding a remote session?

It seems to work for ssh, but not for other remote shell or terminal clients, and neither does it work for screen sessions that connect to remote hosts. What's the protocol it uses to recognize the remote session?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.petesodyssey.org/node/234 and some other search hits I found, it specifically recognizes the `ssh` command entered after the kind of prompt that is the default in many Linux distributions (in particular, I found some hits noting that it does *not* work with FreeBSD's defaults).  This suggests that, unless they also provide some kind of escape sequence that you could use (as some other terminal emulators do), you won't easily be able to make it work in other cases.